# While loop over numbers doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to python and I am trying run this piece of code, however, the while loop doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
def whilelooper(loop):
    i = 0
    numbers = []


    while i < loop:
        print "At the top i is %d" %i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += 1
        print "numbers now:",numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" %i

    print "the numbers:",

    for num in numbers:
        print num


print "Enter a number for loop"
b = raw_input(">")

whilelooper(b)
```

Comment: What do you hope for the code to do and what actual behavior do you observe? Also, please [edit] the code to fix the indentation.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string...  you need `whilelooper(int(b))`

Comment: By the way, `for i in range(loop)` would be "safer" than a while loop

Comment: @cricket_007  made the change... it still seems to be going on beyond the entered value. I needed the range to be set according to the  user's input

Comment: What do you mean "seems"? Either it is, or is not. Please [edit] the quesiton with the updated code and what is being printed (as text, please, not an image)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you soo much. Adding "loop = int(loop)" solved the problem

Comment: @PriyankaYadav that was me but you're welcome :D

Comment: You may use the checkmark next to the answer below to accept it

Comment: @BenJones Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is inputted as a string type, but the comparator

```
while i < loop:
```

is expecting both i and loop to be of type int (for integer), in order to be able to compare them.

You can fix this by casting loop to an int:

```
def whilelooper(loop):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    loop = int(loop)
    ...
```

Comment: Or `whilelooper(int(b))`

Comment: Better to do it inside the function, because it's always going to want to be an int for the function to work